# Gradle processResources - file contains $ character

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

How can you execute `gradle processResources` on files that contain `$` characters without escaping the `$` in the files?

---

I have some static html files located the `/resources/static` folder as suggested by the [Spring Boot reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content). However, when I try to execute `gradle processResources`, Gradle throws an exception

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 
Could not copy file '[...]/src/main/resources/static/dollar.html' 
to '[...]/build/resources/main/static/dollar.html'.
[...]
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error 
or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript7.groovy: 1: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" 
or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 1, column 10.
out.print("""<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As far as I understand, the problem occurs because there is a `$` character in one of the static files and `$` is a reserved character for expressions when processing resources.

---

Proposed solutions:

1. Yes, escaping the `$` with `\$` (as suggested in the stacktrace) works, but I rather not change the html file if other options are available.
2. Trying to exclude the file from process resources causes the problem to disappear, but has the side effect of also excluding the file from being copied:

   ```
   configure(tasks.processResources) {
       exclude 'static/dollar.html'
   }
   ```
3. I have also seen that you can filter processed resources. I guess that this is what I would like to do but I have not found a "ignore $ filter", is there any?

   ```
   configure(tasks.processResources) {
       filesMatching('static/dollar.html') {
           filter = ???
       }
   }
   ```
4. Other suggestions?

---

The `dollar.html` file that causes the problem can be simplified to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Dollar $</div>
</body>
```

Comment: processResources normally just copies the resources, without doing anything else. You're probably using expand (https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:expand%28java.util.Map%29) to replace ${someProp} placeholders by values. Show us your build file.

Comment: @JBNizet You assumption was correct, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33701058/303598) below. Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696246/gradle-processresources-file-contains-character?noredirect=1#comment55167170_33696246) provided valuable insight. The problem was indeed due to the usage of `expand()` (although not immediately visible since it was located in an `allProjects()` script in the parent project). The reason why `expand()` was added in the first place was the desire to populate the [info.build.*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion-gradle) properties in the `application.properties` file (so that they are available through Spring Boot's [info endpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info)).

---

Solution: Use `filesMatching()` to only `expand()` selected files. The following snippet solved the specific problem related to Spring Boot:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

Comment: if the properties key contains the dot char . 
eg  `a.b.c.d=yes`
how to bind it ?
i meet the exception `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property`

Comment: I have my `application.yml` in `:root:subprojectA` classpath. What path does `fileMatching` read ? Also, what should I write in case of YAML configuration with multiple profile ?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference:

You could write the $ also as HTML entity: `&dollar;`