# How to get version variable from build.gradle file into java spring boot controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I know how to get it if version is defined in application.properties, but how do I get it from build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

The general flow is:

1. Define a property in your application.properties that has placeholders, i.e. `gradleVersion=${version}`.
2. Configure Gradle's default task that copies your resource files out to the build directory (called `processResources`) to [filter / expand those properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33701058/862594)
3. Read in the `gradleVersion` property like any other Spring property

Note that it'll require you to invoke Gradle in order to properly resolve the `gradleVersion` property (as Gradle is the one putting the value in there). `bootRun` should already depend on `processResources`, so if you're using that you should be fine.

Comment: I have put this code in my build.gradle:
processResources {
    filesMatching('application-bootrun.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}

in same file I have:
allprojects {
    ...
    version = '0.3.0'
    ... }
How do I acces version in application-bootrun.properties?

Comment: Put `gradleVersion=${version}` in your .properties file, then run the Gradle task `processResources` and look in `./build/resources/main/application-bootrun.properties` to see if the value was correctly expanded. If it was, you can `bootRun` your app and read in the property just like any other property.

Comment: It works very well when I compile my code using gradle (`gradlew build`). However, when I use VSCode's 'run java' or 'debug java' feature, it seems this substitution does not work and I get `Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value "${version}"`. Any idea would be appreciated.