# How to fix springboot gradle:processResources with binary files

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a SpringBoot application using gradle.
But I have some issue with the processResources task.

In my case, I have some JAR files in 'src/main/resources/libs', these files are used to my JAVA BuildPath.

I have allready try to add filter on application.properties only, but it's doesn't work.([Gradle processResources - file contains $ character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696246/gradle-processresources-file-contains-character))

I have this error on 'processResources' task:
`Could not copy file 'xxx\src\main\resources\libs\myJar1.jar' to 'xxx\build\resources\main\libs\myJar1.jar'.
...
Root cause: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript11.groovy: 1: unexpected char: '\' @ line 1, column 232.
   6wPíÔà¬ÑüçZ Ç�8X›y«Ý«:|8“!\dÖñ%BW$   J
                                 ^`

Comment: first question is: why do you put some jar files into a SOURCE directory? (src/main/resources ). If you really need to add some libs into your project you should add these in a `$projectRootDir/libs` and configure classpath (dependencies) to point on these.

Comment: For adding these files in my buildPath. And these Jar arent in repository.

Comment: I updated my previous comment: can you put these jars somewhere else in your project structure ? outide `src` directory.

Comment: When i put it in `$projectRootDir/libs`, it's ok for Jar files. But i got the same issue with '*.png' files now...

Comment: can you post your build file?  the part that configures the `processResources` task. and what version of Gradle are you using?  Normally, wrapping the `expand` block in a proper `filesMatching` block should work, as described in the SO solution you mentioned

Comment: I'm using `gradle 5.0` and my proccessResources is like the solution that I have mentionned.  
`processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processResources {
    filesNotMatching("**/libs/*") {
        expand( // my application properties that should be filtered
                'project': ['version': project.version],
                'build': ['timestamp': new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')]
        )
    }
}
```

Similar to the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36731250/2611959